# Rails - good way to convert string to array if not array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, parameters

I receive a param and want it to be either a string like this :

```
"abc,efg"
```

or an Array like this

```
["abc","efg"]
```

In the first case I want to convert it into an Array, what would be the good way ?

Here is what I thought

```
if params[:ids] && params[:ids].is_a? Array
     ids = params[:ids]
else if params[:ids]
    ids = params[:ids].split(",")
```

Comment: Yeah your code makes sense, seems fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a ternary for this to keep it simple and on one line:

`ids = params[:ids].is_a?(String) ? params[:ids].split(',') : params[:ids]`

I've reversed the order so you don't get an undefined method error if you try calling `split` on `nil` should `params[:ids]` be missing.

Comment: This not only works, but also explicitely checking for instance of `String` (and eventually converting it to array) clearly states your intentions and makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.wrap(params[:ids]).map{|x| x.split(',')}.flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for piling on. But I thought I would offer a slight tweak to the answer proposed by SickLickWill (which doesn't quite handle the `Array` case correctly):

```
ids = params[:id].split(',').flatten
```

This will handle the `String` case just fine:

```
:001 > params = {id: "abc,efg"}
:002 > ids = params[:id].split(',').flatten
 => ["abc", "efg"]
```

As well as the `Array` case:

```
:003 > params = {id: ["abc","efg"]}
:004 > ids = params[:id].split(',').flatten
 => ["abc", "efg"]
```

If there's any chance the `id` param will be nil, then this barfs:

```
:005 > params = {}
 => {} 
:006 > ids = params[:id].split(',').flatten
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```

So, you could put in a conditional test:

```
:007 > ids = params[:id].split(',').flatten if params[:id]
 => nil
```

Or, use `try`:

```
:008 > ids = params[:id].try(:split, ',').try(:flatten)
 => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss `end` tag and you have wrong `else if` and you can delete the check of `params[:ids]` because if `:ids` key do not exist `is_a?` return `NilClass`

I think you can do this

```
ids = if params[:ids].is_a? Array
          params[:ids]
      elsif params[:ids]
          params[:ids].split(",")
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest way would be to use `.try`.  It saves you from writing out an if-then-else.

```
params_id = params[:id].try(:split, ',')
```